# Detect if ACAccount credential is valid

Tags: iphone, ios, social-framework

Is there a way to detect if an `ACAccount` has a valid credential?

The use case is to ensure that an `ACAccount` that was previously retrieved using `requestAccessToAccountsWithType` is still valid. I have registered for `ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification` but I'm not confident that will cover all cases in which a credential could become invalid (for example a server side change to the account?).

Comment: Did you ever get a solution? I could really use this now... Thanks!

Comment: Nope. So far it has not been an issue so I basically just live with it.

Comment: Backup your phone. Buy a new phone. Restore from backup. Launch Twitter. Twitter asks for a password. Enter it. Use Twitter. Sadly, the password is NOT entered into the AccountStore database. Grrrr....